# how can I make a minus in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Something is wrong in my query when I do a subtraction. I am using MS SQL.

```
SELECT PT.PcbId
  FROM dbo.DeviceTrace DT  
  JOIN dbo.PcbTrace  PT ON DT.CompId = '101125937' 
                       AND DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID

NOT IN (SELECT PB.PcbId
          FROM dbo.DeviceTrace DT 
          JOIN dbo.PcbTrace  PT ON DT.CompId = '101125937' 
                               AND DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID 
          JOIN dbo.PanelBlockTrace PB ON PB.PcbID = PT.PcbID)
```

Can you please correct me?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-wrote your query as:

```
SELECT PT.PcbId
  FROM dbo.PcbTrace PT 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM dbo.DeviceTrace DT 
                WHERE DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID 
                  AND DT.CompId = '101125937')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM dbo.PANELBLOCKTRACE pbt 
                    WHERE pbt.pcbid = PT.pcbid)
```

...because you copied your first join into the NOT IN portion, but there's no relation between PANELBLOCKTRACE and DEVICETRACE based on the information you provided.

Comment: exists clauses are bad for performance, because it traverses the whole table until it finds a matching value. a not exists is much worse, as it has to traverse the whole table to confirm a value doesn't exist. An inner join or a left join (with null check )works to better use the indexes..

Comment: @M.R.: You're mistaken - EXISTS exits on the first match, which makes it a better choice if duplicates can be expected.  LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is only more efficient on MySQL when dealing with non-nullable columns - see: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/ vs: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: @OMG Ponies , what does it mean SELECT NULL ?

Comment: @Night Walker: The SELECT clause in an `EXISTS` is not evaluated - you can replace the `EXISTS (SELECT NULL` with `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0`, which should produce a division by zero error.  You'll find it won't, and the query will work properly.

Comment: @OMG Ponies , one more question , you didnt do any joins in your syntax , can you explain where the joins are coming here

Comment: @Night Walker: The joining is occurring in the WHERE clause.  For this query, JOINs aren't the best idea because they will produce duplicates of PCBTRACE records if there's more than one DEVICETRACE record associated to them - you'd need to add `DISTINCT` to get a unique list.  If you compare the subtree cost, you'll find in SQL Server the EXISTS is better for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the field name when you say 'not in' - like this:

```
select PT.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT 
on DT.CompId = '101125937' and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID

and [fieldName] not in 

(select PB.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT 
on DT.CompId = '101125937' and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID 
INNER Join dbo.PanelBlockTrace PB
on
PB.PcbID = PT.PcbID)
```

Or if you want to have it on a separate where clause, then you need:

```
select PT.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT 
on DT.CompId = '101125937' and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID

where [fieldName] not in

(select PB.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT 
on DT.CompId = '101125937' and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID 
INNER Join dbo.PanelBlockTrace PB
on
PB.PcbID = PT.PcbID)
```

Although, you should really use a 'left join' than a 'not in', which will be much faster..

Comment: The JOINs in the NOT IN portion are extraneous.  And LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is not faster on SQL Server: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I left it as is, without knowing what the logic is for... but yes, taking the example at face value, u are right :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks from your query as if you're wanting to exclude those PcbID that are in `PanelBlockTrace` meeting your CompID filter criteria.

Try this:

```
select PT.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  
INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT on DT.CompId = '101125937' 
                            and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID
LEFT JOIN dbo.PanelBlockTrace PB ON PB.PcbID = PT.PcbID    
WHERE PB.PcbID IS NULL
```

I'd prefer this solution above over a `WHERE PT.PcbId NOT IN` because it'd require the one hit to the tables, rather than 2 that a `NOT IN` would require.

Answer (score 1):

test this:

```
select PT.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT 
on DT.CompId = '101125937' and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID
where PT.PcbId
not in 

(select PB.PcbId
from dbo.DeviceTrace DT  INNER Join dbo.PcbTrace  PT 
on DT.CompId = '101125937' and DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID 
INNER Join dbo.PanelBlockTrace PB
on
PB.PcbID = PT.PcbID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EXCEPT instead of NOT IN, as:

```
SELECT query1

EXCEPT

SELECT query2
```

Answer (score 0):

You query seems fine.

If something is wrong, please be more specific.

Also, this query below is equivalent to yours:

```
SELECT PT.PcbId
FROM dbo.DeviceTrace DT  
  JOIN dbo.PcbTrace  PT ON DT.CompId = '101125937' 
                       AND DT.DeviceID = PT.DeviceID

EXCEPT

SELECT PcbId
FROM dbo.PanelBlockTrace
```

It has a simpler structure and may help you to spot the problem more easily.